# Java Calendar Date

Tags: java, date, java.util.calendar

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    
    System.out.println("Current date : " + (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                        + "-"
                        + now.get(Calendar.DATE)
                        + "-"
                        + now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

why are we adding +1 to `now.get(Calendar.MONTH)` to get Current Date? Thanks in advance.

Comment: because java month is zero based... January is considered zero. While in the real world, January is the first month (1)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also for printing it in a human friendly format use `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Example: `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M-d-y"))`. In my time zone it just gave `7-10-2021`. And there’s no funny adding 1.